# Rabbitmq cluster setup in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, kubernetes

I successfully setup rabbitmq cluster using docker compose to understand the clustering concept. It worked fine below is docker compose file:

```
rabbit1:
  image: ipf-queue-node
  hostname: rabbit1
  cap_add:
    - ALL
    - NET_ADMIN
    - SYS_ADMIN
  ports:
    - "5671:5671"
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"

rabbit2:
  image: ipf-queue-node
  hostname: rabbit2
  cap_add:
    - ALL
    - NET_ADMIN
    - SYS_ADMIN
  links:
    - rabbit1
  environment: 
   - CLUSTERED=true
   - CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1
   - RAM_NODE=true
  ports:
      - "5675:5671"
      - "5673:5672"
      - "15673:15672"
```

Docker file content:

```
FROM queue-base

# Create directories
RUN mkdir /opt/rabbit
RUN mkdir /opt/simulator
RUN mkdir /opt/simulator/tools

# Add the files from the local repository into the container
ADD rabbitmq.config     /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD rabbitmq-env.conf   /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD erlang.cookie       /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
ADD startclusternode.sh /opt/rabbit/
ADD debugnodes.sh       /opt/rabbit/
ADD tl                  /bin/tl
ADD rl                  /bin/rl
ADD rst                 /bin/rst

# Add the simulator tooling
ADD simulator_tools/   /opt/simulator/tools/
ADD ./testca /tmp/ssl
ADD ./server /tmp/ssl

# Set the file permissions in the container
RUN chmod 644 /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
RUN chmod 644 /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
RUN chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
RUN chmod 777 /opt/rabbit/startclusternode.sh
RUN chmod 777 /opt/rabbit/debugnodes.sh
RUN chmod 777 /bin/tl
RUN chmod 777 /bin/rl
RUN chmod 777 /bin/rst
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/simulator

# Set ownership permissions on files in the container
RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

# Expose ports inside the container to the host
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 5671
EXPOSE 15672
EXPOSE 25672

# Run this to debug the cluster nodes by allowing ssh login
#CMD /opt/rabbit/debugnodes.sh

# Run this to autostart the cluster nodes
CMD /opt/rabbit/startclusternode.sh
```

startclusternode.sh is the script to setup the cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/tmp/rabbitnode.log"
firsttimefile="/tmp/firsttimerunning"

curhostname=`hostname`
username="<<username>>"
password="<<password>>"
echo "" > $logfile
echo "New Start Date:" >> $logfile
date >> $logfile
echo "" >> $logfile

( sleep 40 ; \
rabbitmqctl add_user $username $password ; \
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags $username administrator ; \
rabbitmqctl add_vhost $curhostname ; \
rabbitmqctl add_vhost localhost; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p $curhostname $username ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p localhost $username ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
) & 

sleep 5

# For version 3.5.6 the first time running the cluster needs to enable the plugins
if [ -f $firsttimefile ]; then
  echo "First Time Running Enabling Plugins" >> $logfile
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -d &
  echo "Waiting for RabbitMQ Server to start" >> $logfile
  sleep 3
  echo "Enabling Plugins" >> $logfile
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp rabbitmq_management  rabbitmq_management_agent rabbitmq_management_visualiser rabbitmq_federation rabbitmq_federation_management sockjs >> $logfile
  echo "Waiting for Plugins to finish" >> $logfile
  sleep 1
  echo "Stopping the RabbitMQ using stop_app" >> $logfile
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app
  echo "Stopping the RabbitMQ using stop" >> $logfile
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop

  echo "Stopping the RabbitMQ Server" >> $logfile
  kill -9 `ps auwwx | grep rabbitmq-server | awk '{print $2}'`
  sleep 1

  echo "Done First Time Running Enabling Plugins" >> $logfile
  rm -f $firsttimefile >> $logfile
  echo "Done Cleanup First Time File" >> $logfile


  # Allow the cluster nodes to wait for the master to start the first time
  if [ -z "$CLUSTERED" ]; then
    echo "Ignoring as this is the server node" >> $logfile
  else
    if [ -z "$CLUSTER_WITH" ]; then
      echo "Ignoring as this is the cluster master node" >> $logfile
    else
      echo "Waiting for the master node to start up" >> $logfile
      sleep 5
      echo "Done waiting for the master node to start up" >> $logfile
    fi
  fi
fi


if [ -z "$CLUSTERED" ]; then

  echo "Starting non-Clustered Server Instance" >> $logfile
  # if not clustered then start it normally as if it is a single server
  /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server  >> $logfile
  echo "Done Starting non-Clustered Server Instance" >> $logfile

  # Tail to keep the foreground process active.
  tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/*

else
  if [ -z "$CLUSTER_WITH" ]; then
    # If clustered, but cluster is not specified then start normally as this could be the first server in the cluster
    echo "Starting Single Server Instance" >> $logfile
    /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server >> $logfile

    echo "Done Starting Single Server Instance" >> $logfile
  else
    echo "Starting Clustered Server Instance as a DETACHED single instance" >> $logfile
    /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached >> $logfile

    echo "Stopping App with /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app" >> $logfile
    /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app >> $logfile

    # This should attempt to join a cluster master node from the yaml file
    if [ -z "$RAM_NODE" ]; then
      echo "Attempting to join as DISC node: /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH" >> $logfile
      /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH >> $logfile
    else
      echo "Attempting to join as RAM node: /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH" >> $logfile
      /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH >> $logfile
    fi
    echo "Starting App" >> $logfile
    /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl start_app >> $logfile

    echo "Done Starting Cluster Node" >> $logfile
  fi

  # Tail to keep the foreground process active.
  tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/*

fi
```

Problem is when I tried to do the same setup using kubernetes I am unable to connect to master from slave node. Approach that I took is, I created a pod for master node and another for slave node, passed hostname of the master (currently hard-coded) through environment variable. I also checked the log file at /tmp/rabbitmq.log, it is correctly taking all the environment variables. However it is unable to register with the master. I tried doing it manually also using rabbitmqctl command. But it did't work says host unreachable. Tried changing /etc/hosts file too.

As per my understanding pods in kubernetes communicate through services, I guess because of this, passing directly container hostname doesn't work and rabbitmq clusiering work based on hostnames.

Have anybody tried any workaround? I want to run master and slaves on different nodes. Below are the content of master and slave pods:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmqsvc
  labels:
    app: queue-master
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5672
      name: queue-rw-port
    - port: 15672
      name: queue-mgt-port
      nodePort: 31606
    - port: 5671
      name: queue-ssl
      nodePort: 32718
  selector:
    app: queue-master
  type: NodePort
  clusterIP: 10.16.0.121
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-controller
  labels:
    app: queue-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: queue-master
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-pod
      labels:
        app: queue-master
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        nodesize: small1
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq-master
        image: 172.17.0.1:5000/queue-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: queue-rw-port
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: queue-mgt-port
        - containerPort: 5671
          name: queue-ssl
```

SLAVE:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmqsvc-slave
  labels:
    app: queue-slave
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5672
      name: queue-rw-port
    - port: 15672
      name: queue-mgt-port
      nodePort: 31607
    - port: 5671
      name: queue-ssl
      nodePort: 32719
  selector:
    app: queue-slave
  type: NodePort
  clusterIP: 10.16.0.122
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-controller-slave
  labels:
    app: queue-slave
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: queue-slave
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-pod
      labels:
        app: queue-slave
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        nodesize: small2
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq-slave
        image: 172.17.0.1:5000/queue-node
        env:
        - name: CLUSTERED
          value: "true"
        - name: CLUSTER_WITH
          value: "rabbitmq-controller-2ll1s"
        - name: RAM_NODE
          value: "true"
        - name: HOST_NAME
          value: "rabbit2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: queue-rw-port
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: queue-mgt-port
        - containerPort: 5671
          name: queue-ssl
```

Comment: Is there a description how I can install rabbitmq in kubernetes with minikube/kubectl (don't need cluster)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Docker hostnames and links with Kubernetes. It works only when you have one machine, but Kubernetes is designated to be clustered solution.

Enable [DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns) in your cluster. Create `Master service` (rabbitmqsvc - already done) and then use DNS name of your `Master service` in you slave configuration:

```
    - name: CLUSTER_WITH
      value: "rabbitmqsvc.svc.cluster.local"
```

You can use also [environment variables](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/environment-guide/README.html), but IMHO DNS is better option.

Comment: Or use the `clusterIP` of your master service if you don't have the DNS add-on running.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..I already tried using service Cluster IP, RABBITMQSVC_SERVICE_HOST  nothing works. Problem is with rabbitmq cluster setup. I can't use IP, domain name of service for cluster setup it requires the hostname of the node. I think I have to setup it outside the cluster in the same vnet. Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: Got it working finally. Changed /etc/hosts file and mapped ip with the host-name and it started registering the nodes..Will change the script now and will try to automate this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a description how I can install rabbitmq in kubernetes with minikube/kubectl (don't need cluster)?

Answer (score 3):

We just open sourced a deployment ready rabbitmq cluster for kubernetes.
It uses StatefulSets so it requires Kubernetes 1.5.X or later.

You can find it here: https://github.com/nanit/kubernetes-rabbitmq-cluster

Comment: Getting the following error using nanit:

+ echo 'Waiting for RabbitMQ pod to be ready....'
Waiting for RabbitMQ pod to be ready....
++ kubectl get pods -n test2
++ grep rabbitmq-0
++ grep Running
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo 'RabbitMQ pod still not ready...'
RabbitMQ pod still not ready...
+ sleep 5