# Expose 5671 port in Docker and Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azureservicebus

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API service that receives messages in Service Bus using Docker / Azure Kubernetes, but am having trouble with the port blocked.

Here is my deployment files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8004
EXPOSE 5671
EXPOSE 5672

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8004 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyTest.dll"]
```

**Deployment.yml**

[image]

**Service.yaml**

[image]

Seems it is all that is needed? But it still cannot access Service Bus.

Comment: How are you accessing?
You need to access via node's IP, look like: Node_IP:3xxxx

Comment: You seem to have included two PNG files in place of your YAML files.  Those aren't searchable or runnable; `kubectl apply -f` will just complain if I try to run it.  Can you replace these with the actual text of what you're deploying?

Comment: (If you're running the RabbitMQ broker in a separate StatefulSet, you don't need to declare anywhere that you're making outbound connections to it; you do not need Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directives or to mention port 5672 in the Kubernetes YAML anywhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> You seem to have included two PNG files in place of your YAML files. Those aren't searchable or runnable; `kubectl apply -f` will just complain if I try to run it

> (If you're running the RabbitMQ broker in a separate StatefulSet, you don't need to declare anywhere that you're making outbound connections to it; you do not need Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directives or to mention port 5672 in the Kubernetes YAML anywhere.)

You can refer to [Rabbitmq cluster setup in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397430/rabbitmq-cluster-setup-in-kubernetes)